# Routes in zend framework 2

Tags: module, zend-framework2

I am trying hardly to put the routes for some controllers in zend framework 2 and even after I read a lot I can't figure why it still tells me The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class. I have a module named CRM and in the src folder I have Contacts and Companies, each of them having Controller/Form/Model. This is my module.config file:

```
     array(
         'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
              'CRM\Controller\Contacts' => 'CRM\Controller\ContactsController',
          'CRM\Controller\Companies' => 'CRM\Controller\CompaniesController',
    ),
),


'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'contacts' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/contacts[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Contacts\Controller\Contacts',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'companies' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/companies[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Companies\Controller\Companies',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),



'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'contacts' => __DIR__ . '/../view/crm',
        'companies' => __DIR__ . '/../view/crm',
    ),
),
```

);

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question and your structure correctly, you need to set up the namespaces in your autoloader config...

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                // CRM
                __NAMESPACE__  => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                // Contacts
                'Contacts' => __DIR__ . '/src/Contacts',
                // Companies
                'Companies' => __DIR__ . '/src/Companies',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: I just tried adding these lines in getAutoloaderConfig(), but it seems it still doesn't work. The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Comment: @user2047893 Sorry, you'll still need to map the controllers in the `invokables` section of your controller config (ie change the `CRM` prefix you have there now with `Contacts` and `Companies` respectively)

Comment: I see just now that you wrote the second comment. Yeah, that was indeed the problem. I modified them already and it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your config you have Controller invokables configuration:

```
'CRM\Controller\Contacts' => 'CRM\Controller\ContactsController',
```

The first value in the above is an identifier. This is what you are meant to use within your route definitions. For example your `contacts` route - try changing the following:

```
'defaults' => array(
     'controller' => 'CRM\Controller\Contacts',
     'action'     => 'index',
),
```

Comment: I tried that already, but after I change CRM instead of Contacts it gives me a Fatal Error that the class can't be found in ..\vendor\..\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170. Any idea?

Comment: Now check the class file has the right namespace and class name to match CRM\Controller\ContactsController.

Comment: As well as your `module.config.php`s `getAutoloaderConfig()`

Comment: is there anyway to show you the project structure? I mean I have it like this: module->CRM->src->Contacts->Controller->ContactsController.php, and the namespace in the php file is Contacts\Controller; The getAutoloaderConfig() is there and worked before, when my module name was Contacts as the entity in src.

Comment: There seems to be a few issues here. Sort out the class name and namespace first. If your file structure is `CRM/Contacts/Controller/ContactsController.php` then your namespace is likely to be `CRM\Contacts\Controller` and your classname is `ContactsController` (This depends on how you have set-up the autoloader). Inside the configuration update the controller invokables use the full classname - `'CRM\Controller\Contacts' => 'CRM\Contacts\Controller\ContactsController'`. But Crisps answer may be a better fit if your project.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you all for your time, I managed to solve it. Those lines written by Crisp were indeed the issue, but I still had to modify the invokables and write instead of CRM, Contacts, respectively Companies.